# How do I center cells in table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to center my cells horizontally in my table view. Currently, they stick to the left. How do I go about doing this?

I've looked up various questions on SO and webpages, but they're all in Objective C, and I use Swift.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to center the cells of your table view.  You should allow Cocoa to manage the size of your cells and you should center your content within the content view of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to do:

First, you need to make sure you set the table style to Default: `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`. All other styles use a detailTextLabel in one way or another and you won't be able to set the textLabel's alignment property.

```
UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
```

Then you can set the alignment of your cell's textLabel:

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = .Center
```

Comment: in func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
}

Comment: FYI, I don't want to centre the text, just the cell in the view.

Comment: are you using custom tableview or using storyboard

Comment: My table view is custom, but I'm also using storyboard,

Comment: make constraints of your tableview according to your need

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches as listed below

1- you have to create cell w.r.t tableview width but drag your cell content in centre from nib.

2- You have to decrease tableview size so your cell fit with tableview.

Answer (score 0):

if don't subclass the tableview cell, then subclass the `UITableViewCell`
and just override below method,
in `CustomCell` add below method

```
override func layoutSubviews() 
{
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.frame  = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + 100, self.frame.origin.y, 100 , 100);
    //option 2
    // self.bounds  = CGRectMake( 100,0, 100 , 100);//calculate centre
}
```

in above u must use current `frame` react and calculate the `centre` according to your requirement, as u see i use the current frame of the cell if u ignore this, the x and y position set to zero the cell is always at the (0,0,width,height) of the tableview

and also also u can also use  `bounds` it worked i comment it as option 2